# Xpath explanation in code

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

In the company I am working I had to dive in this part of code. One of your parses is failing and there is a suspicion that there is a fault in this part of code but I due to my inexperience cant figure exactly what its supposed to do.

```
from lxml import etree
uni = etree.tounicode

def results(self):
    return [(e.attrib['href'], uni(e))
            for e in self.doc.xpath('//li[@class="g" and not(class="localbox")]//a[@class="l"]')]
```

Comment: "A fault" is awfully general. Would you be able to edit your question to provide 1) a relevant bit of the XML file -- alter/remove top-secret information if necessary, 2) expected output, and 3) current output? or a full traceback if an exception is being raised...

Comment: @Adam The purpose is to parse results from Google search. Google builds the results in an ul and gives relevant classes, 

<li class="g"> 
<h3 class="r">Bar</h3>
<a href="foo.html" class="l"></a></li>

Comment: This question is meaningless without also providing the XML document against which the XPath expression is evaluated. Please, remember to do so from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression does the following:

```
//li[@class="g" and not(class="localbox")]//a[@class="l"]
  ^        ^              ^                 ^       ^
  1        2              3                 4       5
```

1. find all occurences of `<li>` elements
2. that have an attribute named `class` with value `g` (example `<li class="g">`)
3. that dont have a subelement `class` with string-value `localbox` (will explain this later)
4. afterwards it finds all `<a>` elements "inside" those `<li>` elements
5. that have an attribute name `class` with value `1` (example `<a class="1">`)

The fun part is 3. Probably there is a `@` missing in front of `class`. In that case the statement would have been: 3. that dont have an attribute name `class` with value `localbox`.

Implicit string-value conversion and comparision of node elements is... error prone to say the least. I don't think you want something like that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: _The fun part is 3. Probably there is a @ missing in front of class. In that case the statement would have been: 3. that dont have an attribute name class with value localbox._ - what is the reason to check for `@class="g" and not(@class="localbox")`? the second is always true, if the first is true.

Comment: @khachik - My guess is that the target element has multiple class names (separated by spaces) and this is a misguided attempt to retrieve only those elements having one but not the other.

Comment: @khachik Do you have an idea for example how to check about the links that have class="l" or no class?

Comment: @Chris-Top @lwburk: I just said that if `@class="g"` in that case the second is always true: `not(@class="localbox")`, so changing `class="localhost"` to `@class="localhost"` is meaningless.